All of the async workers quit. When doesn't asyncio.run return?
Anyone know why this asyncio.run fails to exit in this program when the child process quits?
I run the program below, and then pkill ssh to kill the ssh process.
AFAICT all of the async workers:

runcommand
read_from_process
write_to_process
have all quit. The program prints:

finally... worker 1 done
finally... worker 2 done
t1, t2 done
finally
finally .. DONE  returncode=255

But "ALL DONE" is not printed until return is printed (and ps confirms that the python process did not quit).
import asyncio
import os
import pty
import sys
import termios
import traceback
import tty

async def run_command(command):
    # Create a pseudoterminal pair (master and slave)
    master_fd, slave_fd = pty.openpty()
    old_tty = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)

    try:
        # Set the terminal in raw mode for capturing control characters
        tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
        # Start the process using the slave as stdin, stdout, stderr
        process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(
            *command,
            stdin=slave_fd,
            stdout=slave_fd,
            stderr=slave_fd
        )

        # Close the slave in the parent process
        os.close(slave_fd)


        # Start tasks to handle reading from and writing to the terminal
        async def onCancel(coro, proc):
            try:
                await coro
            except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
                termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_tty)
            except OSError as e:
                termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_tty)
                # Cancel other end.
                if proc == 1:
                    t2.cancel()
                else:
                    t1.cancel()
                # process.kill()

                # print("".join(traceback.format_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__)), file=sys.stderr)
                # cancel_task(t1)
                # cancel_task(t2)
                # print("".join(traceback.format_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__)), file=sys.stderr)
            except Exception as e:
                termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_tty)
                print("".join(traceback.format_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__)), file=sys.stderr)
            finally:
                termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_tty)
                print(f"finally... worker {proc} done")
                # cancel_task(t1)
                # cancel_task(t2)

        t1 = asyncio.create_task(onCancel(read_from_process(master_fd), 1))
        t2 = asyncio.create_task(onCancel(write_to_process(master_fd), 2))

        await asyncio.gather(t1, t2)
        print("t1, t2 done")
        await process.wait()

        # asyncUtil.printWorkers() # Shows only run_command coro remains

    finally:
        print("finally")
        # Restore the terminal to its previous state
        os.close(master_fd)
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_tty)
        print(f"finally .. DONE  returncode={process.returncode}")


async def read_from_process(master_fd):
    """Asynchronously read from the master side of the PTY and print to stdout. Note that stdin/stdout are combined."""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    while True:
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, os.read, master_fd, 1024)
        if not data:  # EOF
            break
        sys.stdout.write(data.decode())
        sys.stdout.flush()


async def write_to_process(master_fd):
    """Asynchronously read from stdin and send input to the process."""
    try:
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        while True:
            try:
                user_input = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.read, 1)  # Read one character
                if user_input == "\x04":  # CTRL+D to signal EOF
                    os.write(master_fd, user_input.encode())
                    # print("CTRL+D")
                    break
                if user_input == "":
                    break  # EOF, such as CTRL-D
                os.write(master_fd, user_input.encode())
            except EOFError:
                break
    except Exception as e:
        print("".join(traceback.format_exception(type(e), e, e.__traceback__)), file=sys.stderr)


# Run the main event loop with the command
command = ["ssh", "localhost"]  # replace with your SSH command
asyncio.run(run_command(command))
print("ALL DONE")
sys.stdout.flush()


It's because of this not finished thread user_input = await loop.run_in_executor(None, sys.stdin.read, 1)

Oh good catch. Makes sense. I printed out the list of thread and it confirms what you say. I guess asyncio.run waits on the thread pool even though all the async tasks are complete. Weird that that threads were recommended do this. Thinking about it, it looks terribly inefficient  vs async select/epool.
